# How to hide the keyboard that pops up in RubyMotion?

Tags: rubymotion

How does one hide the virtual keyboard that pops up in a text field?

The button that hides it does not seem to appear and in my case, the next screen that loads (which does not have a text field) will still have the keyboard in the loaded position.

Thanks!

Update:

Using the following allows the keyboard to return:

```
  def textFieldShouldReturn textField
     textField.resignFirstResponder
    'YES'
  end
```

However, it still remains open upon the next screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be true instead of 'YES' and don't forget to set the textfield delegate

```rb
 def textFieldShouldReturn textField
    textField.resignFirstResponder
    true
  end
```